# Server Out Of Memory

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When running a custom solution in SharePoint 2013, we are getting an issue in the uls log

> Server Out Of Memory.
>
> There is no memory on the server to run your program. Please contact your administrator with this problem.
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PreInitServer(String bstrAbsoluteRequestUrl, String bstrServerRelativeUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gApplicationId, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String bstrDatabasePassword, Boolean fHostHeaderIsSiteName, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMajor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMinor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionBuild, Int32 iDatabaseVersionRevision)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PreInitServer(String bstrAbsoluteRequestUrl, String bstrServerRelativeUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gApplicationId, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String bstrDatabasePassword, Boolean fHostHeaderIsSiteName, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMajor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMinor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionBuild, Int32 iDatabaseVersionRevision)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.PreinitializeServer(SPRequest request)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetProperties()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPropertyBag..ctor(GetProperties getProperties, UpdateProperties updateProperties)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Properties()
> at PointFire2010.PFHttpModule.a(SPWeb A_0)
> at PointFire2010.PFHttpModule.d(Object A_0, EventArgs A_1)
> "

Please let us know how to resolve this issue and we are facing this issue for a client where as it is running fine with other client end.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a good handle on how much RAM you have but one thing that I know I often run into in getting this error is the page file. Generally speaking, you want your page file to be at least twice the size of your available RAM and in some cases (especially with crawl servers) 3 or more times. Note that that *does* mean that the more RAM you have, the *more* disk space you need.

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM you have on your Server? Also check the available disk spaceon the drive where sharepoint is installed and notice which process is consuming lot of memory, check it through Task Manager.

Here's an article on common reasons for running out of server memory in SharePoint. Please take a look.

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949.aspx

http://blogs.edwardwilde.com/2009/12/15/server-out-of-memory-there-is-no-memory-on-the-server-to-run-your-program-please-contact-your-administrator-with-this-problem-at-microsoft-sharepoint-library-sprequestinternalclass-applywebtempl/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610240/sharepoint-application-working-server-out-of-memory-there-is-no-memory-on-the

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for server out of memory error.

As you mentioned, you have custom solution installed in sharepoint, did you properly dispose all the objects in code after using it? Make Sure no memory leaks in your code.

Other things to check: Make sure enough ram & disk space available on SharePoint Severs as well as on the SQL Server.

Did you see any other errors in ULS /Event log related to the same correlation ID?

[A bug, saboteur, or am I going crazy... SharePoint 2010 Farm That Keeps "breaking"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35555/a-bug-saboteur-or-am-i-going-crazy-sharepoint-2010-farm-that-keeps-breakin)

[Another good link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6290496c-2018-4d6a-8461-4b29bc6199d8/error-server-out-of-memory-there-is-no-memory-on-the-server-to-run-your-program-please-contact?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)